# Delete ID From DB

Tags: php, mysql

**Original Form**

```
  <?php
echo '<td><form action="episodesdelete.php" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="epid" value="'.$row['epid'].'">';  
?>
```

**episodesdelete.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't Connect To Server");
$db = mysql_select_db("shows", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't Select Database");
$query = "DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= "'.$_POST['epid']'";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have in-correct usage of double quotes:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= ".$row['epid']"';
```

Should be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= ".$row['epid']";
```

---

**You have one more problem:**

You also need to use `$_POST` array with correct field name like:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= " . $_POST['id'];
```

Because you are using `POST` as method of the form:

```
<form action="episodesdelete.php" method="POST">
```

You need to use `$_POST`

And because your hidden field is named `id`:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['epid'].'">';
```

You need to specify that in your query:

```
$_POST['id']
```

So here is how your query should be:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= " . $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Not Working-MySQL is throwing this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @WideBlade: Are you **submitting** the form? Also when you echo sql query what it outputs?

Comment: @Sarfaz-I'm submitting the form. When I echo the SQL query the output is the error listed above, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: After submitting your form and before your query, put this `echo $_POST['id']` what does it say, it should post back the id that was there in the hidden field which you got into it `value="'.$row['epid'].'"` Where i assume id is inserted into value of hidden field. You can check the source code of the page.

Comment: You should check this line of yours: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['epid'].'">';` I suspect `$row['epid']` is comong empty there, you should check your query.

Comment: Nice SQL injection point. Put ID number manually and then test it. Like Sarfraz said check you SELECT query that should contain epid.

Comment: @webarto - This is the query, not sure I understand properly: $query = "SELECT * FROM house ORDER BY epnumber ASC";

Comment: You should... $result = mysql_query($query); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); print_r($row); to see what elements your result contain. If there is epid in table there also must be in $row variable. Best thing is to post your entire script.

Comment: @webarto-tried this, it pulls out the row out of the database as an array.

Comment: Damn. I feel stupid now-i forgot to add the epid in the DB. I added it before, but I changes the tables and forgot it. Thanks for all the help and sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

please check the source code of the generated html page in the browser.

- Is the value of the hidden input field filled with the correct id and not empty?
- Is the at most one input field with the name id per <form>?

On the server, check that the form was submitted, not just fetched for displaying:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    ...
}
```

You wrote:
    $query = 'DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid= ".$row['epid']"';

There is a number of issues with this line:

- Instead of $row you need to use $_REQUEST or $_POST as it is data sent from the browser
- Instead of "epid", you named it just "id" in the html code.
- Inside single quotes, variables are not substituted
- There is a security issue called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which allows the users to execute any SQL statement they want by sending it as "id"-parameter; for example by using Firebug.

The line should look like this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM shows WHERE epid='"
          .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'";
```

PS: Speaking of security, make sure that you escape untrusted data with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before inserting it into the html page. And you need an unguessable token in the form to prevent other websites, a logged in user may visit, from blindly submitting delete requests. See [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: it is empty. I'm not sure what i did wrong... I changed it to $_post and it still does not work.